# Where do I get the qm executable from?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, gnu-make, qmake

I am working on an Ubuntu 16.04 system and tried to compile an application with the `qm` command as per the readme file in the source directory.  When I try to run the command I get the repose:

```
$ qm
qm: command not found
```

This suggests that my Ubuntu PC does not have a repository with a package that supplies a qm executable setup.  I guess the source code for the tool may be available somewhere and be usable for multiple GNU Linux operating systems.

How do I source and install the qm executable?

The readme file for the code I am trying to compile states that *qm* stands for *q*uick-*m*ake or *QM*ake but I cannot find any reference to these in a google search.  I only find references to Qt's qmake which is not the tool I am looking for based on the errors I get back.

This *qm* tool uses a `defs.mk` file as its instruction set.

The program I am trying to install uses the RAVL Library.  The README file for that library also mentions `qm` command.

Answer (score 1):

I found a source for the `qm` or QMake or Quick Make tool.  In the [Recognition And Vision Library (RAVL) Installation Instructions](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/Ravl/RavlDoc/share/doc/Ravl/Auto/Basic/Tree/Ravl.Installation.html) the installation of QMake is mentioned.

> Building the RAVL library requires the use of an ANSI C++ compiler
>   along with the GNU make utility (or another compatible version of
>   make). The RAVL build process is actually managed by the QMake
>   utility. QMake is a flexible compilation aid, designed to provide a
>   simpler interface to the GNU make program. As part of the RAVL
>   installation process, a copy of QMake will be configured and
>   installed.

The instructions go on to explain that by; obtaining a copy of the RAVL source code, configuring, making and installing it you get both the RAVL libary and the quick-make tool set.  This includes the `qm` command.

After preforming the following steps:

```
git clone -b tested_nightly git://git.code.sf.net/p/ravl/ravl ravl
cd ravl
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```

I am able to use the *qm* command.